# Is there a way of iterating through objects and only access certain values via their key? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, ejs

So basically, I'm making a request to the newsapi, translate the response in English and then store the translated in an object (Since I only want certain data from the response).

I'm using EJS to pass the data from backend to frontend. I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and have done countless research.

---

For instance, I only want to access the title in the object, pass it on to the frontend via EJS and use h1 for it. Use h3 for the description and image tag for images etc.

Here's my code:

```
 response.on("end", function () {
            const newsData = JSON.parse(newsItems);
            for (let i = 0; i < newsData.articles.length; i++) {
                async function quickStart() {
                    try {
                        const [translation_title] = await translate.translate(newsData.articles[i].title, 'en');
                        const [translation_desc] = await translate.translate(newsData.articles[i].description, 'en');
                        const [translation_content] = await translate.translate(newsData.articles[i].content, 'en');
                        const readMore = newsData.articles[i].url;
                        const img = newsData.articles[i].urlToImage;
                        const publishedAt = newsData.articles[i].publishedAt;
                        const emptyObjArray = {
                            title: translation_title,
                            description: translation_desc,
                            content: translation_content,
                            datePublished: publishedAt,
                            url: readMore,
                            imgURL: img
                        };

                        //Testing loop
                        for (const values in emptyObjArray) {
                            console.log(emptyObjArray);
                        }

                        res.render("newsList", { newsItem: emptyObjArray });

                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error();
                    }
                }

                quickStart();


            }


        });
```

My ejs code:

```
<section id="headline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h1>Before for loop</h1>
      <h1>==============</h1>
      <h1><%= newsItem.title %></h1>
      <h4><%= newsItem.content %></h4>
      <h6>Published : <%= newsItem.datePublished %></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img src="<%= newsItem.imgURL %>" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: _"I've been stuck on this problem..."_ - What problem?

Comment: You might want to look at [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys); it will give you an array of the object keys that you can use for iteration

Comment: Why is there a function in the `for` loop?

Comment: Hello @Andreas, I just realised I didn't give enough context:  I only want to access certain values in the object via their keys and loop through the entire object, capturing only the data that I want.

Comment: @Andreas Because I'm capturing individual item from the response (All of the possible response) and then store it in an object variable.